# Efficiently find the root of thousands of objects in a dotnet memory dump?

Tags: .net, .net-5, lldb, memory-dump, dotmemory

So I have an 18gb memory dump from a dotnet 5 program running on linux. I need to find the root for thousands of objects. Right now I am using lldb, but it is taking around 20mins to find the root for just one object. Are there any tools or processes that can do this quick and efficiently?

Comment: You've already tagged dotmemory, which is exactly for such situations. I don't think it runs on linux, but for memory analysis, you could probably also test your app on windows?

Comment: Note also that there is not a single root element in a .NET application. Every static object is a potential root.

Comment: There is console dotMemory which allow getting snapshots on linux. Also standalone dotMemory on windows supports .NET Core memory dumps collected on Linux.